# Difficulties with encoder while training VAE

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

A VAE is comprised of two parts: encoder and decoder. The encoder should take the input and then output a mean $\mu$ and a variance $\sigma^2$. Then, sampling occurs with $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and that passes to the decoder, which will try to reconstruct the original signal. The loss function has a KL divergence term between $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where the goal is to make $\mu=0$ and $\log(\sigma) =0$. In my case, when training the encoder neural network what happens is exactly that, but for all inputs, namely, $f_\mu(x)=0$ and $f_\sigma(x)=0$ for all $x$, where $f_\mu,f_\sigma$ are the encoder network. Therefore, no matter what the input is in the encoder, the decoder will always output roughly the same because it is just sampling $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Use a weaker regularization term.

Comment: If the prediction is EXACTLY $f_\mu(x) = 0$ and $f_\sigma(x) = 0$, it sounds like you may have a bug in your code. If it is not exactly that, but roughly that, you may need to increase the weighting of the reconstruction term, or anneal the loss term. The loss (called ELBO) has both a regularization term( i.e. the KL divergence term you refer to), and a reconstruction term. Because training is hard, and the regularization term just makes it harder, it is common to start with a small coefficient for the regularization term, and slowly increase it up to the final value. This is called annealing.

Comment: It is not exactly 0. It is very close to 0, in fact in terms of sampling, I don't think there's any difference if the mean is 0.002 or 0.001, which are the orders of number I am getting. I'll try adding a weight to the KL term. :)

Comment: @mgarort why do you say that if $f_\mu(x)=0$ and $f_\sigma(x)=0$, then there is probably a bug in my code?

Comment: @Schach21 because it would be a great coincidence that the predicted mean and log-variance was exactly the same value for every datapoint, right? In the real world, I expect the datapoints to change slightly, and the output of the encoder to change slightly too. If a neural network (or any predictor) always predicts a constant, that suggests a bug to me.

Comment: Regarding the annealing of the regularization paper, you can check out this paper, for example: _Generating Sentences from a Continuous Space_ by Bowman et al. https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06349  (section "KL cost annealing" and Figure 2). Hope this helps :)

Comment: @mgarort I agree with you, except that I am using ReLu in the preceding layers to the output. So, if the output becomes 0 there, it doesn't matter what happens after. One solution would be to change ReLU for tanh, I suppose. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll take a look at the paper.